# Issue creating an APP inside the Foursquare dashboard

Tags: foursquare

Cannot create Foursquare App in Developers Dashboard ***/developers/apps***. Used both Facebook account and personal email for creating a user, but still cannot create successfully APP. I found similar questions from 2015, but is it still the same issue in place?

```
{meta: {code: 400, errorType: "other", errorDetail: "Must provide parameter code",…},…}
meta: {code: 400, errorType: "other", errorDetail: "Must provide parameter code",…}
notifications: [{type: "notificationTray", item: {unreadCount: 0}}]
response: {}
```

Comment: Facing the same issue.